# How to configure security (IIS, token, etc.) for a website that uses SharePoint 2013 REST API?

Tags: jquery, security, rest

I have a website that uses the SharePoint 2013 REST API to render list data (via JQuery AJAX) on the website. It is pretty straightforward and works fine, but my challenge is figuring out the security component. I was under the impression that the credentials of the Identity that is running the app pool for the website in IIS would be sent through to SharePoint via the REST API. It looks like this may not be the case and that it might be sending the credentials of the user logged into the computer - it's hard to tell. The goal would be to use a service account to facilitate the communication from the website to SharePoint via the REST API. Is there an IIS setting to do this? Do I have to use the client-side token on the API-call side or even use the cross-domain library?

Comment: following link may help you.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022(v=office.15).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179927.aspx

Comment: I've gone ahead and implemented the JS to use the cross-domain library (via SP.RequestExecutor.js). However, when I run the code, it says "App Web is not deployed for this app's request url". This makes sense considering I obviously need to register the app somewhere, otherwise someone could just include the SP.RequestExecutor.js library and fire off JS to access the SP site. However, this is not an App for SP, it's a custom ASP.NET public-facing website that needs to consume list data from SP. Can I still register the website's url even if it isn't an SP App project?

Comment: I'm assuming I have to create an app url in the Configure App Url's section (in Central Admin) under App Management? Which will then generate a ClientId and ClientSecret that I can add to my ASP.NET project? Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to get me the desired result. It looks like creating the app url is only for SP-specific apps and NOT the type of site I am creating. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like MS doesn't really support anonymous access on the REST API quite yet...Spoke to folks at TechEd in Houston.